# Any possible to way to ignore decorators only for tests?

Tags: webpack, decorator, ecmascript-next

I am currently running in to an issue with decorators in my unit tests written for a reactjs application.

I love the way we avoid so much boilerplate by introducing decorators in our react components, components are looking clean and code become more readable with this.
But now feeling irritated too much this nonsense decorators, because I am unable to run a single unit test which is a must test in my application context. Code described below:

```
@translate(['common'])
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
 ...
 componentDidMount() {
  // Ajax call on success setting the state this.setState({ myData: response.data })
 }
 ...
}
```

Want to test this component state, I received from a ajax success response.

My test looks as below

```
describe('<MyComponent />', function () {
 sinon.stub(dataService, 'fetchData')
  callsFake(function () {
   return Promise.resolve(['one', 'two', 'three'])
  });
 it('should match the state with data fetched', function () {
  const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
  return dataService.fetchData()
   .then(function () {
    expect(wrapper.state('myData')).to.have.lengthOf(3);
   });
 });
});
```

Above test works well if I remove @translate(['common']) from my component, but doesn't work if exists.
I know translate is a HOC and I need to adjust my test accordingly but believe me I tried everything, nothing works for me.
Also there is a way to get this working by adding multiple export in component one is pure and other is wrapped with translate but for this solution also I have to drop the decorators which I like to have in my source code.

So is there any way we can configure our webpack to ignore or skip these decorators from my source code during running my tests?

Comment: Decorators are not part of ES7.

Answer (score 0):

Because decorators are just sugar for [Higher-Order Functions](https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html) you can separate the class declaration and the decoration of the class, however you lose the pretty `@` decoration syntax because [*you can only use decorators on an export when exporting a class*](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4EE4G8C-AUIQAIAmwC0KM0hokscFAZigK5LxbEvsB2CGAEsI_ZpWq0ocABQBKPPiA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3%2Ces2015-loose&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0):

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
 ...
 componentDidMount() {
  // Ajax call on success setting the state this.setState({ myData: response.data })
 }
 ...
}

export default translate(['common'])(MyComponent)
```

In your tests you can now import the underlying, "undecorated" class:

```
import {MyComponent} from '...'
```

> So is there any way we can configure our webpack to ignore or skip these decorators from my source code during running my tests?

I don't believe there exists any way to make webpack ignore the decoration of classes. It *would be possible* to create some plugin that parsed files and removed decoration statements, but this is overkill and would have myriad implications on other parts of the application development and build process.